# How can I implement an auto load more data function on scroll?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have been stuck on this for like two days. I am displaying a list of topics. Everything is working fine, but whenever I scroll to the bottom of the page, I want to add more data to the list just like on popular social media sites.

Here is my get-topic.php

```
<?php
include_once 'resources/Wall.php';
$Wall   = new Wall;
global $databaseConnection;
$username_get = mysqli_query($databaseConnection, "SELECT * from tableTopics order by columnTopicId desc limit ".$topicsPerPage."");
$numberRows = mysqli_num_rows($username_get);/* get the total number of rows and put it in a variable */
$loopCount = 1;
$html .= '  <div class="topics-box">';
while ($name = mysqli_fetch_array($username_get)) {/* loop through the topics */
    $topicId = $name['columnTopicId'];
    $topicTitle = $name['columnTopicTitle'];
    $getPic = $Wall->getTopicPicture($topicId);
    $html .= '  <div class="topic-header">
                    <img class="topic-picture" src="'.$getPic.'">
                    <a class="topic-title">'.$topicTitle.'</a>
                    <a class="topic-action-button"><div class="icon-more topic-action-button-icon"></div></a><a class="topic-follow-button"><div class="icon-footprints topic-follow-button-icon"></div>Follow</a>
                </div>
                <div class="topic-stats">
                    <div class="topic-right-stat">54k Followers</div>
                </div>';
    if ($loopCount < $numberRows) {
        $html .= '<div class="topics-border"></div>';
    }
    $loopCount ++;/* add 1 to the loop count everytime */
}
$html .= '  </div>';
echo $html;
?>
```

Here is my js function

```
function loadMoreTopics() {
    alert("hi");
}
```

I call that function whenever the user scrolls to the bottom of the page using this code.

```
        jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
            if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() == jQuery(document).height() - jQuery(window).height()) {
               loadMoreTopics();
            }
        });
```

I have tried using several examples of Ajax but none of them work for me. What Ajax function should I use? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jQuery Scrollbox plugin](https://github.com/Invis1ble/scrollbox). You can use it to easily implement desirable functionality. Just define container in your html and use the following code:

```
var $container = $('#content-container');

$container
    .on('reachbottom.scrollbox', function () {
        $.ajax({
            // options like url, dataType etc.
        }).done(function (response) {
            $container
                .append(response)
                .scrollbox('update');
        });
    })
    .scrollbox({
        distanceToReach: {
            y: 100
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many plug-in's available for the same. You can implement it on own using Jquery like:

```
$(function() {
   loadResults(0);
    $('.country').scroll(function() {
      if($("#loading").css('display') == 'none') {
        if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
           var limitStart = $("#results li").length;
           loadResults(limitStart); 
        }
      }
    }); 

function loadResults(limitStart) {
    $("#loading").show();
    $.ajax({
        url: "request.php",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            limitStart: limitStart
        },
        success: function(data) {
               $.each(data, function(index, value) {
               $("#results").append("<li id='"+index+"'>"+value+"</li>");
             });
             $("#loading").hide();     
        }
    });
};
});
```

[Working Demo](http://lab.iamrohit.in/sload/)

[Reference Code](http://www.iamrohit.in/dynamically-load-data-on-div-scroll-using-php-mysql-jquery-and-ajax/)